# jQuery change time of setInterval using range input

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

I am trying to access the time value of setInterval, however I am new in jQuery and JavaScript and I am not sure how can I achieve this. Here is what I have for now:

```
<form name="form4" oninput="amount.value=rangeInput.value">
    <input type="range" id="rangeInput" value="1000" name="rangeInput" min="1000" max="10000" step="500"/>
    <output name="amount" for="rangeInput">1000</output>
</form>
```

And the code would be:

```
$(function randomName() {
    setInterval(function(){ 
        //alert("some text");
    }, 10000);
});
```

Here is a fiddle of what I have for now https://jsfiddle.net/mLk3wb50/

Is there a way to change the value of time, link it to the range input?

Basically, I would like to execute the alert or whatever action at intervals set by the range input. Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: You will need to cancel and restart the interval timer if you want change the time interval.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to be the way. You will need to clear the interval before reinitializing it.

```
function someFunc(){ alert("hi"); }
var interval;

$(function randomName() {
    interval = setInterval(someFunc, 10000);;    
});

$("#rangeInput").on("change", function(){
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(someFunc, $(this).val());
});
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mLk3wb50/1/)**

Comment: An alert seems to be a bad way of debugging timers :) Best promote use of `console.log` as a better debugging aid.

Comment: @Guarang Tandon Thank you! It works! However, I have a question: it seems that the code did not work until I wrapped it into another function, and recalled that function "onload="function_name()" in the body tag (and the script is added before all my other scripts, this is how it worked). This way, if I change the value of the input, before the whole page loads, it runs a few times with the initial value (or at all, I am not sure of this, as it happened once). Is there a way I can recall the function on a different event, not onload in the body, so that I can change the value immediately?

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie You are right :) I added it in a hurry.

Comment: @DantèsCristo Sorry for late reply. Hmmm... as far as i understand from what you say, if you want a different event, just do: `$(element).on("event", func)` yo call `func`, if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to change the interval:

```
 function myFunc(){ alert('hi'); }

 var myInterval = setInterval(myFunc, 1000);

 function changeInterval(){
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    myInterval = setInterval(myFunc, 2000);
 }
```